# Floating Div for Wrapped Text With Linked Image Inside

Tags: html, css

Trying to float an image to the left of some text. The image needs to be linked to something. The link, however, is only working on parts of the image.

See code here: http://jsfiddle.net/JaUXp/

```css
#rightImg {
    float: right; 
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
}

#leftTxt {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="rightImg">
    <a href="http://google.com">
        <img src="myimg.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
<div id="leftTxt">
    <p>my text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason my left DIV had a position property set to "relative" was because of normalize.css. My solution was to set the position property on the DIV to "static".

Comment: I've confirmed this works in FF24, Chrome 30 and IE8.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe looking for something as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/DJruJ/

```
HTML
<div id="container">
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_new">
        <img src="http://image.yaymicro.com/rz_512x512/0/4fd/pile-from-dominoes-on-black-background-4fd987.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
<div id="description">
    <p>One late author did indeed venture to assert, and  to prove, that the tendency to move, the power or force that produces actual motion, is </p>
</div>


css

#container {
    float: left; 
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0 10px 15px 0;
}
#container img{
    width:100%;
}
#description {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

you are using "rightImg" and "leftTxt" as element id's. Its not recomended to use such kind of naming conventions because in future your left text may become right text and vice versa your image. in that case it might be a bit confusing

hope this helps